# How does the nftables set-syntax replacement for meters work exactly?

Tags: linux, configuration, firewall, nftables, syntax

nftables nowadays [recommends](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Meters) to use sets instead of meters when e.g. creating dynamic per-IP blacklists (example adapted from [man pages](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/nftables/nft.8.en.html) v0.98:

```
set blackhole {
    type ipv4_addr
    flags dynamic
    timeout 30m
}

set flood {
    type ipv4_addr
    flags dynamic
    timeout 1m
}

ip saddr @blacklist drop

ct state new \
  add @flood { ip saddr limit rate over 10/minute } \
  add @blacklist { ip saddr } \
  drop
```

1. How is the execution flow of the `add`-statements here? The second `add` is only executed when the per-ip limit specified in the first `add` is hit, but why? Does it have something to do with whether the first `add` actually does anything (i.e. there is no entry in the table yet)? Or does it do some magic by looking at the set and the number of connections created so far?
2. Is the `drop` always executed? Or just after the second `add` is evaluated? Why?
3. How does the lookup table help to keep track of the limit? When I view the actual contents of the set, I don't see any counts of e.g. new connections in the last minute. Does it just store the timestamp and delegate the actual counting to the kernel?
4. Why do we need to specify the flood limit interval twice (as the set `timeout` and in the `limit` statement)? Are there use-cases where it makes sense to use two different values?
5. The [Red Hat 7 docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_nftables_to_limit_the_amount_of_connections) give this example for a per-IP connection limiter:
   `nft add rule ip filter input ip protocol tcp ct state new, untracked limit rate over 10/minute add @denylist { ip saddr }`

This seems incorrect to me as the rate is put *before* the `add`, meaning it will just add the IP to the table as soon as it hits 10 new connections/minute from *any* IP?

Pointers to docs on the actual semantics of the language are appreciated.